# Unity: AI suggestions for "Tiny Wings" like game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on game similar to the mobile game "Tiny Wings".

[Image of Tiny Wings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5D3g.png)

Like shown in the image you are supposed to land on the downhill part of a mountain. If you are fast and high enough you can fly past mountains without having to land and slide down. How can I create an AI that knows when to land and when to fly past the hill? (I'm using "AddForce" to push the "bird" down when the player decides he wants to land) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a simple problem that can be solved in a single answer.(At least I don't feel this to be the case.) But i can give a couple pointers as to how i would attack this problem. So it could get more complicated than this but this seems like a good place to start.

- First I would have a range of optimal angles for landing the bird in the "butter zone"
- Second you will have to keep track of the birds rotation/angle in relation to the ground
- Third you will have to build a system based on the birds velocity to seek out a "target" landing spot
- Fourth you will have to adjust the angle of the bird to be as close to parallel with the landing spot as possible.

  Hopefully this will get you started, but this seems like it's going to be a somewhat hefty task. Good luck.